# angularjs $http.put changes my URL

Tags: angularjs, http, request, angularjs-http

I was trying to make a $http.put request with angularjs.
What I do is just:

```
$http.put("http://mi-url/personalized_product_custom_pages/2")
```

What it really does is a request to:

```
"http://mi-url/personalized_product_custom_pages"
```

Somebody knows why it changes my URL? how can I add the id?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally it was an internal error. This question should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You may try , $http.put(url, data); instead of directly giving the data.
ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

Comment: can you put the exactly answer for the question? I kept trying with different syntax but it doesn't work yet...

Answer (score 0):

Try with `params`:

```
$http.put("http://mi-url/personalized_product_custom_pages", params:{id:2})
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it makes a request to "http://mi-url/personalized_product_custom_pages"